# How to check if variable in while condition is a number?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have a do while loop and I need to check if the variable in the while condition is a number. How do I do that?

```
do {
       try
       {
           String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
           int number= Integer.parseInt(n);  
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException e)
       {
           System.out.println("Not a Number");
       }
    } while (????);
    System.out.println("You entered a number");
}
```

}

Comment: You could do a `while (true)`, and insert a `break;` statement after the `int number` statement.

Comment: due to scoping you dont have a variable in the while loop..

Comment: while is not for what you are intended to do. use while for looping, the condition in while should be to check whether the loop should continue or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean:

```
boolean isNotNumber = true;
do
{
    try
    {
        String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
        int number= Integer.parseInt(n);
        isNotNumber = false;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Not a Number");
    }
} while (isNotNumber);
System.out.println("You entered a number");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following code:

```
do {
        try {
            String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(n);
            if (number <=0|| number >0){
                break;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a Number");
        }
    } while (true);
    System.out.println("You entered a number");
}
```